# How i am cleaning the label after one displaying of an incrementation by port using arduino?

Tags: c#

I am trying to increment an value in Arduino and send it on port and after that to display it in a label in real-time.

even that I put and delay(200) and Thread.sleep(200);

```
namespace Receiver
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort port;
        public Form1()
       {

            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Form1_FormClosed);
            if (port == null)
            {
                port = new SerialPort("COM9", 9600);//Set your board COM
                port.Open();
            }


        }
        void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (port != null && port.IsOpen)
            {
                port.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Afisare_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                string a = port.ReadExisting();
                afisare.Text = a;
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in change I got all the values, one by after one,down the screen some of them.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running an endless loop in your `Afisare_Click` handler that runs in the same thread as you UI. This means that the UI will not be able to render the control changes.

`Thread.Sleep` code switches the context to other threads, but not the UI thread.

Your approach should be using [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8).

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Interval = 200;
        _timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    private void _timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // This function will be called every 200 ms.
        // Read the information from port, update the UI.

        string a = port.ReadExisting();
        afisare.Text = a;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        _timer.Stop();

        if (port != null && port.IsOpen)
        {
            port.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using UITimer = System.Windows.Forms.Timer;
UITimer _timer = new UITimer();  Done! Thank you!!!